# правильно описать OnSaveInstanceState (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android, activity-life-cycle, onsaveinstancestate

Использую в приложении два TextView, кнопку Button и Exoplayer. Подскажите как правильно сделать сохранение состояния приложения при нажатии кнопки "Назад" (Back). Суть в следующем: пользователь загружает приложение, нажимает кнопку Play - играет плейер, в текстовые поля загружается информация по restapi запросу, в общем красота. Как только нажимаю кнопку "Назад" (Back) в фоне остается играть плейер (это в принципе неплохо, логика нормальная), а при возврате текстовые поля очищаются и становятся пустыми. Логику OnPause-OnStop-OnDestroy посмотрел, жизненный цикл понятен, по восстановлению OnStart-OnResume - тоже.
Описал процесс таким образом, но что-то пошло не так... Как быть?

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    outState.putString("ARTIST_NAME",textView.toString());
    outState.putString("TRACK_NAME", trackView.toString());
    outState.putBoolean("DETECT", isEnabled);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    textView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("ARTIST_NAME"));
    trackView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("TRACK_NAME"));
    isEnabled = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("DETECT");
    }
```

Comment: Используйте класс Preferences. Это позволяет сохранить данные в файле. onSavedInstance работает не при всех сценариях.

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/preference.php

Answer (score 0):

Да, действительно ссылка сработала.
Описал логическую переменную через "Запись" перед уничтожением:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = psettings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(APP_PLAYER_ENABLED,isEnabled);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

После достаю ее следующим образом:

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        psettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean hasVisited = psettings.getBoolean(APP_PLAYER_ENABLED, false);

        if (!hasVisited){
         ......//здесь пишу свой код на выполнение
        }
    }
```